# About matrix operations

Tags: c, matrix

This is a theoretical question, there is no need to show code.

So, I would like to know how to return the result of a sum function, which will add two arrays using pointers.

1. First, should matrices be declared as a pointer right at the beginning?
2. So, in the function we will have

void sumMatrix (int ** m) (?)

From here, how to proceed to return the result of this sum, since the matrix itself cannot be returned

Comment: What kind of arrays are we talking here? Known size? If so what are the dimensions?

Comment: You don't need to return if you `call by reference`

Comment: It doesn't have a specific dimension, it could be 2x2 as an example. Can you explain to me how can I do this (the call by reference), please?

Comment: C does not have call by reference, only call by value.  But you can pass a pointer (by value) to allow the called function to modify the object it points to.  This is how in/out and out parameters are implemented / simulated in C.

Comment: Ok, but how do I return the sum result in the function?

Comment: If `sumMatrix` is passed one parameter, `int **m`, where does it get two input matrices from? Is `m` a pointer to where the result goes, or two one of the two matrices, or to somewhere that both matrices are found in some way, or something else? How does `sumMatrix` know what size the matrices are?

Comment: I basically want the step by step of what to do, from the moment of declaration of the matrix until the return of the sum result in the function, the size of the matrix does not matter, it can be 2x2

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. It is for specific questions. Whatever book you are using or course you are taking should have taught you what you need to know to do the exercises. Use the information that was taught.

Answer (score 1):

Options include:

1. Pass the function a pointer to where you want the result matrix stored.
2. Write code in the function to allocate space for the result matrix and return a pointer to that space.
3. Create a structure type to hold the result matrix and have the function return that structure by value.
4. Write the results into one of the input matrices.

Comment: Can you show me step by step what I should do (really written, you don't need the code) from the declaration of the matrices until the return of the result of the function? please

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to pass arrays of any dimension to functions in C.  It is impossible even to express the concept, because in most circumstances, including function-call expressions, values of array type are automatically converted to pointers.  Thus,

1. Your function has no alternative but to receive its arguments in the form of pointers.

However, you should give some thought to the specific pointer types.  C multidimensional arrays (e.g. `int arr[3][4]`) are structured as arrays of arrays, and the aforementioned automatic conversions yield pointers to arrays (`int (*p)[4]`), not pointers to pointers.  On the other hand, you can construct arrays of pointers (`int *arr[3]`) and use the same syntax to access them as one does with multidimensional arrays.  The automatic conversion of these to pointers does yield double pointers (`int **p`).  Despite the matching access syntax, these alternatives very different in terms of memory layout and access efficiency.

2. It depends.  Ignoring the for the moment the question of returning the sum, you have at least three good alternatives:

- `void sumMatrix(int r, int c, int **m1, int **m2);` This is appropriate for array of pointers data layout.  You an express the same thing as
  `void sumMatrix(int r, int c, int *m1[], int *m2[]);`, and I would probably be inclined to do that myself.
- `void sumMatrix(int r, int c, int m1[r][c], int m2[r][c]);`  This is equivalent to
  `void sumMatrix(int r, int c, int m1[][c], int m2[][c]);` and to 
  `void sumMatrix(int r, int c, int (*m1)[c], int (*m2)[c]);`
  These rely on the variable-length array feature added to C in C99, and it is worth knowing that this feature became optional in C11.  It assumes compact, efficient array-of-array data layout.
- `void sumMatrix(int r, int c, int *m1, int *m2);` or, equivalently,
  `void sumMatrix(int r, int c, int m1[], int m2[]);` This supposes the same array-of-array data layout as the previous, but requires you to perform the index calculations manually (`x * c + y`).  It is useful if you want to have array-of-array layout with variable array dimensions, without depending on VLAs.

Personally, I would be inclined to choose array-of-arrays layout and one of the variations on the second signature option.

> From here, how to proceed to return the result of this sum, since the matrix itself cannot be returned

You again have multiple options, but I would be inclined to add a fifth parameter, of the same type as the third and fourth, representing the result matrix.  Because, again, it is necessarily a pointer, the data written into the pointed-to object by the function will be visible to the caller.  The caller will then be responsible for passing a pointer to an existing object, which is convenient because it allows (but does not require) using an automatically allocated object.

Thus one complete possibility would be

```
void sumMatrix(int r, int c, int m1[r][c], int m2[r][c], int result[r][c]) {
    // ...
}
```

which could be called like this:

```
int a[3][4], b[3][4], c[3][4];

// ... fill arrays a and b ...

summMatrix(3, 4, a, b, c);
// the result is in matrix c
```